# Header and footer with fixed position while content is scrollable?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to make a website where header and footer have fixed position while content scrolls in the middle.

```
<header style="position:fixed"></header>
<div id="content">some content</div>
<footer style="position:fixed"></footer>
```

I created what I thought would work but it doesn't. Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbhUf/1/) with the whole thing.
As you can see, part of content is hidden under the footer and beyond (I can't see 'HELLOWEEN' in the end). What must I change to fix it? Thanx

Comment: That fiddle works for me on Chrome. I changed the top line to 'Home 1" and it appears just under the red bar when the scroll bar is moved to the top.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest fix for this is to add padding equivalent to the height of your static header and footer:

```
#content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7S4Xx/)

Comment: @MichalArtazov At first glance this looks like the solution until you scroll the content.  The scrollbar overlaps the header which is not ideal since the header is not scrolling.  It should be that the content section itself has a scrollbar only and the header and footer have no scroll bar.  See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yASFU/) provided by peterchon solution.

Answer (score 6):

http://jsfiddle.net/yASFU/

```
<header>header</header>
<section>
    <div class="push">push</div>
</section>
<footer>footer</footer>

html, body {height:100%; margin:0; overflow:hidden;}
header, footer {display:block; background-color:black; height:10%;}
section {height:80%; background-color:lightblue; display:block; overflow:auto;}
section .push {height:4000px;}
```

Comment: that's one way to do it but not suitable for my situation, anyway thanx

Answer (score 3):

1. remove the position styles on the header and footer
2. set a height on the content
3. add a style overflow-y:auto to the content

If you want the content height to match the browser window (less the header and footer), use javascript to set it (and adjust on window resize events)

Comment: also interesting solution but not suitable for my situation, anyway thanx