# Bootstrap fixed header and footer with scrolling body-content area in fluid-container

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, less

I was surprised I could not find a simple answer to this problem by Googling, but most responses to scrolling content panels either did not work properly, or did not work with bootstrap.

Answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215780/header-and-footer-with-fixed-position-while-content-is-scrollable) have full page scroll-bars, which seems wrong.

I am simply trying to have 100% height `html` and `body` with no browser scrollbar, but scrolling visible on the body content area only. It needs to behave with bootstrap menu heights etc.

So far the only way seems to work, at all, is using absolutely position content and footers elements.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
html body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html body .container-fluid.body-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
}
```

But this just seems the wrong way to go about it and seems to impact Bootstrap layouts negatively. For instance, if the menu line wraps to two lines, the content area goes under the nav-bar div.

Can any please tell me the correct way to go about this styling, that is compatible with an out-of-the-box MVC Razor/Bootstrap application?

### Notes:

- It needs to work with IE8 onwards.
- It needs to work with Bootstrap, so if Boostrap is adjusted (header/footer sizes) then it will correct itself too.

### Update:

Here is a JSFiddle to work with (including my latest solution from answer below):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6cbrjrt5/

Comment: is this not a super common use case? Why doesn't it work with bootstrap? I tried without bootstrap and I can do it, but then all kinds of weirdness ensues with bootstrap.  What is in bootstrap that is making fixed positioning behave in non-standard ways?

Answer (score 24):

Add the following css to disable the default scroll:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And change the `#content` css to this to make the scroll only on content body:

```
#content {
    max-height: calc(100% - 120px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0px 10%;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

[**See fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7S4Xx/240/)

---

***Edit:***

Actually, I'm not sure what was the issue you were facing, since it seems that your css is working. I have only added the HTML and the header css statement:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
html body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html body .container-fluid.body-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #4C4;
    height: 50px;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #4C4;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header></header>
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want a set height for his header and footer.

Comment: @Chad Hmm, you're right. I'll review my answer asap. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Question updated, with a JSFiddle, if you want to improve upon it. Thanks.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I think you'll need to (a.) use javascript to constantly calculate the remaining body-content height in pixels, or (b.) use multiple media queries handling each header and footer line wrapping. Is any of these an option? If yes, I can work on it later. If no, I think it won't be possible with pure CSS. It would be tough to prove the impossibility, but in fact, I would also like to wait for a good answer, since it seems that there is currently no solution on web.

Comment: @falsarella: As it happens I wrote a simple plugin that adds size-based classes to the `body` element on resize, based on the current rendered Bootstrap size, so I *will* be able to vary based on styles alone.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Nice! A javascript solution is indeed suitable. Alternatively, you could use media queries instead of watching for window resize. I'll update my answer with it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 10):

Another option would be using [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

While it's not supported by IE8 and IE9, you could consider:

- Not minding about those old IE versions
- Providing a fallback
- Using a [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13934654/1064325)

Despite some additional browser-specific style prefixing would be necessary for full cross-browser support, you can see the basic usage either on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7S4Xx/491/) and on the following snippet:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
html body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
html body .container-fluid.body-content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
header {
    background-color: #4C4;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
footer {
    background-color: #4C4;
    min-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header></header>
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
  Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>Lorem Ipsum<br/>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Nice one! I'd like to have the header and foot fixed but inside the content I'd also like to have another header that similar sticks to the top of the inner content and on the inner content should be scrollable. When its scrolled the outer header and footer as well as the inner header stay always in place.
I tried http://jsfiddle.net/7S4Xx/569/ but the inner footer is not visble. Also the same construct should still work like your with content like in your first fiddle

Comment: @philk That's because your `outerContent` should be the flex wrapper, instead of an inner inner flex wrapper. [Please, take a look how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/7S4Xx/593/).

Answer (score 2):

Until I get a better option, this is the most "bootstrappy" answer I can work out:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6cbrjrt5/

I have switched to using LESS and including the Bootstrap Source NuGet package to ensure compatibility (by giving me access to the bootstrap `variables.less` file:

**in _layout.cshtml master page**

- Move footer outside the `body-content` container
- Use boostrap's `navbar-fixed-bottom` on the footer
- Drop the `<hr/>` before the footer (as now redundant)

**Relevant page HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
</footer>
```

**In Site.less**

- Set `HTML` and `BODY` heights to 100%
- Set `BODY` `overflow` to `hidden`
- Set `body-content` div `position` to `absolute`
- Set `body-content` div `top` to `@navbar-height` instead of hard-wiring value
- Set `body-content` div `bottom` to `30px`.
- Set `body-content` div `left` and `right` to 0
- Set `body-content` div `overflow-y` to `auto`

**Site.less**

```
html {
    height: 100%;

    body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;

        .container-fluid.body-content {
            position: absolute;
            top: @navbar-height;
            bottom: 30px;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

*The remaining problem is there seems to be no defining variable for the `footer height` in bootstrap. If someone call tell me if there is a magic 30px variable defined in Bootstrap I would appreciate it.*