# Understanding Top level <router- outlet> and sub module <router-outlet>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am new to Angular framework and creating an angular application. And I have a layout(Header, Body , Footer) where Header and footer should be fixed and they are placed in app.component.html. Only the body needs to be changed based on the click or navigation.
So but right now, I am struck with one issue.

[image]

**App.component.html**

```
 <app-header></app-header>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 <!-- Footer Selector-->
 <app-footer></app-footer>
```

**dashboard component**

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <span class="badge badge-secondary">Badge 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <span class="badge badge-secondary" (click)="navigateToBadge2()">Badge 2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <span class="badge badge-secondary">Badge 3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <span class="badge badge-secondary">Badge 4</span>
      </div>
 </div>
 <router-outlet>
 </router-outlet>
```

Dashboard TS

```
navigateToBadge2() {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/badge2']);
  }
```

Whenever I am clicking the badge, it's navigating properly but the badges are still being displayed.
I wanted to navigate only to badge component without displaying the Dashboard screen.
Below is the result.
I have my header and footer fixed but, the badges are being displayed even if the navigation successful. If I remove the  from Dashboard component. Unable to see the badge content.
Could anyone help me with the scenario.
Thanks in advance

[image]

routing module

```
   { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, children:
    [
      { path: 'badge1', component: Badge1Component },
      { path: 'badge2', component: Badge2Component },
      { path: 'badge3', component: Badge3Component }]}
```

Comment: look through this you may get what you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038596/bootstrap-fixed-header-and-footer-with-scrolling-body-content-area-in-fluid-cont

Comment: That's not what I am facing the issue with

Comment: you still see your badges cause they are in the dashboard component OUTSIDE the router-outlet (where the badge componentg children will be injected) ..

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857876/angular-2-submodule-routing-and-nested-router-outlet

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi. But how do I not display the badges also upon navigating to individual badges

Comment: create ANOTHER COMPONENT .. like indexCompoenent .. put there your badges and andd it as child route ..then set initial route (default) ton your /dashboard/index

Comment: It's a bit confusing though. Can yu give an example and explan

Answer (score 1):

When you access a sub-route it does not leave the parent one. It'll only include a new child route inside the parent one. In your case, you always will be inside "dashboard" route and changing sub-routes will only redraw the sub-route area (the inner router-outlet).

If your desire is to have a route without your badge menu, I believe your best approach would be to create a route in the same level of "dashboard" (using the first router-outlet). Thus, you would navigate using **this.router.navigate(['/badge2']);**